# Python Convert Lines into a list

Tags: python

I use ifconfig command with awk to catch system's ip addresses

```
$ ifconfig  | grep -E 'inet.[0-9]' | awk '{ print $2}'

127.0.0.1
192.168.8.2
```

How to convert o/p into a list using python ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import sys
list_of_lines = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin]
```

Answer (score 3):

You might just skip shelling out to call a pipeline of commands. You can get the IP addresses without leaving Python. If you just need the non-loopback IP:

```
>>> socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
('furby.home', [], ['192.168.1.5'])
>>> socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2][0]
'192.168.1.5'
```

And to get the loopback,

```
>>> socket.gethostbyname_ex('localhost')
('localhost', [], ['127.0.0.1'])
```

There's also a module called [netifaces](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces/0.4) that'll do this in [one fell swoop](http://alastairs-place.net/netifaces/).

Comment: I am not sure if we can know IPv6 addresses by this ?

Comment: That's a good question, and I don't have an answer at the moment. I'll check this out and see what can be done about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
lines = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig  | grep -E 'inet.[0-9]' | awk '{ print $2
}'"]).split('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all . I could do this way.

```
ipa=[]
f=os.popen("ifconfig  | grep -E 'inet.[0-9]' | awk '{ print $2}'")
for i in f.readlines():
     ipa.append(i.rstrip('\n'))
return ipa
```

Answer (score 1):

I just modified the code posted by @Pujan to make it work for linux. (tested in Ubuntu 12.04):

```
import os
ipa=[]
f=os.popen("/sbin/ifconfig | grep -i \"inet\" | grep -iv \"inet6\" | " +   "awk {'print $2'} | sed -ne 's/addr\:/ /p'")
for i in f.readlines():
    ipa.append(i.rstrip('\n'))
print ipa
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys.stdin` to read this output.

Then redirect the output as follows:

```
$ ifconfig  | grep -E 'inet.[0-9]' | awk '{ print $2}' | myProg.py
```